# How can I fill in web forms with Perl?

Tags: perl, forms, automation

I want to fill in a web form with Perl. I am having trouble finding out the correct syntax to accomplish this. As in, how do I go to the URL, select the form, fill in the form, and then press enter to be sure it has been submitted?

Answer (score 12):

Something like [WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller)?

Answer (score 6):

[WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) and its friends are the way to go. There are several examples in [Spidering Hacks](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005771/), but you'll also find plenty more by googling for the module name.

Good luck, :)

Comment: Is there anything that would give me an array containing all the form fields? I'm looking at the WWW::Mechanize form and field methods, and I don't see anything.

Comment: The things that select a form return an HTML::Form object. That's what you use to inspect the form.

Comment: The array I am looking for will come from `@inputs = $form->inputs`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Start with WWW::Mechanize::Shell:

```
perl -MWWW::Mechanize::Shell -e shell
get http://some/page
fillout
...
submit
```

Afterwards, type "script", and save generated code as something.pl - and that's about it. It's done.

Answer (score 0):

Request the form's action URL with `Net::HTTP` or something (can't recall the exact module), and include the forms fields as a `GET`/`POST` parameter (whichever the form calls for).

Answer (score 0):

[HTML::Form](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.825/lib/HTML/Form.pm) works nicely, too.

The synopsis of the module is an excellent example:

```
 use HTML::Form;
 $form = HTML::Form->parse($html, $base_uri);
 $form->value(query => "Perl");

 use LWP::UserAgent;
 $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
 $response = $ua->request($form->click);
```